# Change all &nbsp; to normal blank space Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, console

How do I gsub all `&nbsp;` to normal blank spaces from the Rails console? I have a model called Course and want to replace each course that has `&nbsp;` with the course with a normal blank used rather than the non-breaking space.

So far, I have tried these in the console:

```
courses = Course.all
courses.each { |course| course.gsub!(/\302\240/," ")}

courses = Course.all
courses.each {|course| course.shortname.gsub!(/&nbsp;/i," ")}
```

After restarting my rails server, it still doesn't seem like the changes have taken place. Am I overlooking a simple mistake. It seems like the changes either aren't working in the first place, or they aren't saving.

Comment: You are not saving the Course after you change it. Try `course.shortname.gsub!(/&nbsp;/i," "); course.save!`

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't quite seem to work. I looked at the UTF-8 encoding and want to replace \xC2\xA0 with \x20. Any idea how this would work with gsub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Your changes aren't working in the first place, as you have used wrong pattern, You are supposed to add an "\" before an special character which in your case is "&".

So try this:

```
courses = Course.all
courses.each {|course| course.shortname.gsub!(/\&nbsp;/," ")}
```

`&nbsp` is same as `ASCII code 160`, so

```
courses = Course.all
courses.each {|course| course.shortname.gsub!(160.chr("UTF-8")," ")}
```

Also while trying i noticed the &nbsp is same as "\u00A0" as i got an error as undefined method `html' for "\u00A0":String. I don't know what it is but this might also works,

```
courses = Course.all
courses.each {|course| course.shortname.gsub!("/\u00a0/", "")}
```

Comment: @Jack please let me know weather my anser helped you or not by accepting and voting,

Comment: I have accepted your answer after editing it for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the course. Try:

```
Course.all.each do |course|
  course.shortname.gsub!(/&nbsp;/i," ")
  course.save!
end
```

Comment: It throws the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'save!' for nil:NilClass `and says `'block in irb_binding'`

Comment: Sorry, `gsub!` doesn't return the `course` itself, so that was wrong. I have updated.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything I have to do other than `.save!` to make it change the db? Also, is there a way to see the UTF-8 encoded results for a test. For example if I were to try this out on the course "MATH 231", could I have it return \x4D\x41\x54\x48\x20\x32\x33\x31 in normal UTF encoding?